# Custom sort using spaceship operator in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I am implementing a custom sort. There is the spaceship operator `<=>` to deal with sorting an array:

```
myArray.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }
```

- `a <=> b` returns `1` when `b` is larger than `a`, and the two elements are swapped.
- `a <=> b` returns `0` when `a` equals to `b`, and the two elements stay in the original position.
- `a <=> b` returns `-1` when `a` is less than `b`, and the two element stay in the original position.

So I tested with an example:

```
myArray = [2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0]
myArray.sort { |a, b| 1 <=> 1 } # making it always return 0
#=> [9, 1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 0]
```

The result is not what I expect. In my expectation, when the spaceship operator returns `0`, every element would stay in the original position. Since the spaceship operator always returns `0` in the example above, the array should remain as is. However, the result is different from the original array.

Is there something I misunderstand?

**Updated:**

Following was the idea where my question above came from.
Originally I was trying to order objects by their attributes(Let's assume the attribute is `status`).

For example

```
myObjects = [obj1, obj2,..., objn] # the objects are ordered by create_time already

myObjects.sort{|a,b|
    case a.status
        when 'failed'
            x = 1
        when 'success'
            x = 0
        when 'pending'
            x = -1
     end

     case b.status
        when 'failed'
            y = 1
        when 'success'
            y = 0
        when 'pending'
            y = -1
     end

     x <=> y  # compare two objects (a and b) by the status 
}
```

`myObjects` is ordered by `created_time` already, but I want to sort it again by each object's `status`.

For instance,

Two objects with the same `created time`(only taking hours and minutes into consideration here, just ignoring seconds) will be sorted again by their status, making objects with `failed` status be put at the end of the array.

The `x` and `y` value in the code above will depend on the object's status,
and `x` `y` are compared to decide the order. If the statuses of two objects are equal (`x == y`), the elements should stay in the same position because they are sorted by `created_time` already, no needs to sort them again.

When the status of two objects are both `success`, `x <=> y` will return `0`. 
But according to some comments, the comparison value `0` returned by the spaceship operator seems to output unpredictable order.
What if `myObjects` contains elements all with the **same status**? It would cause the spaceship operator returns 0 all the time since `x == y`.

In my expectation, `myObjects` should remain the same order since the statuses are all the same, how should I correct when using the spaceship operator in my case?

Many thanks to everyone's help!

Comment: It is not space operator, it's spaceship operator. Space does not look like `<=>`.

Comment: "[W]hen the space operator returns 0, every element would stay in the original position"--What does this follow from?

Comment: You could've used `0` instead of `1 <=> 1`, so this is not because of the spaceship operator.

Comment: @sawa Because I think Ruby would swap the elements when 1 is returned as the result of spaceship operator. That's why I think Ruby would leave element alone when it sees 0 or -1. Is my concept correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array#sort` uses Quicksort algorithm, which is not stable and can produce this behaviour when elements are "equal".

Reason is in choosing and moving *pivot* element at every step, ruby implementation seems to choose pivot at middle for this case (but it can be chosen differently).

This is what happens in your example:

1. pivot is chosen at element `9` at middle of array
2. now algorithm ensures that items on left of pivot are less than it and items on the right are greater or equal, because all are "equal" - this makes everything to be in *right* part
3. now recursively repeat for *left*(this is always empty in this case) and *right* partitions
4. result is `sorted_left + [pivot] + sorted_right`, left is empty thus pivot is moved

[Ruby core documentation](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Array.html#method-i-sort) mentions this:

> When the comparison of two elements returns 0, the order of the elements is unpredictable.

Also spaceship operator `<=>` does not play any role here, you could just call `myArray.sort{0}` for the same effect.

### Update:

From updated question it's clear that you want to sort by two attributes, this can be done several ways:

Method1: you can invent a metric/key that takes both values into account and sort by it:

```
 status_order = { 'success' => 1, 'failed' => 2, 'pending' => 3 }
 myObjects.sort_by{|o| "#{status_order[o.status]}_#{o.created_time}" }
```

This is not very optimal in terms of extreme performance, but is shorter.

Method2: implicit composite key by writing comparison rule like this:

```
status_order = { 'success' => 1, 'failed' => 2, 'pending' => 3 }
status_order.default = 0

myObjects.sort{|a,b|
  if a.status == b.status
    a.created_time <=> b.created_time
  else
    status_order[a.status] <=> status_order[b.status]
  end
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  And I've updated my question, looking forward to any advise. Thank you.

Comment: @Wilson.Wang see updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, and that makes me learn more idea.
However I found something that I am still not clear:

Comment: In Method2,  if a.status == b.status, it will compare the created_time, and that's where I am stuck now. Because I thought myObjects was sorted already by created_time, I place x<=>y (x and y depends on object's status, so  x equals to y )in my code, indicating two statuses are identical, and that seems to be the problem that cause the unexpected result?
When encountering same status, is it necessary to compare another thing(like created_time in your example) instead of just using two identical integer which returns 0 as the result?

Comment: @Wilson.Wang yes, when sorting - you may think of previous array state as random and describe your desired end state

Comment: Got it. Very appreciate your detailed explanation and your help!

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption about how the sorting works is incorrect. As per [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) `#sort` is not stable:

> The result is not guaranteed to be stable. When the comparison of two elements returns 0, the order of the elements is unpredictable.

Comment: That makes me be confused again. If the comparison is 0, how to make the array be the same when two objects regarded as the same? (when two objects are regarded as the same object by some attribute)

Comment: @Wilson.Wang there is already another question asking how to make the sort stable. I closed this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the updating and that question also helps me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How it works

```
myArray = [2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0]

myArray.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]

myArray.sort { |a, b| b <=> a }
#=> [9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

If result of comparsion is always `0` it's impossible to sort elements. That is quite logical.

However, the documentation explicitly states that the order of the elements is **unpredictable** in this case. That's why the result is different from the old array.

However, I replicated your situation in Ruby 2.5.1 and it returns old array

```
myArray = [2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0]
myArray.sort { |a, b| 1 <=> 1 }
#=> [2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0]
```

There's also a misunderstanding in your code. You wrote

```
myArray #=> [9, 1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 0]
```

But in fact `Array#sort` doesn't change array, only `Array#sort!` does it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I know that making the comparison always returning 0 value would result in unpredictable result, and there should always be something to compared. Thanks.